# Sorting values in object keeping indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have the following object that I would like sorted:

```
Object {0: 1, 
        1: 2, 
        2: 1, 
        3: 2, 
        5: 2, 
        6: 1, 
        7: 2, 
        8: 1}
```

This is what I would like this to become:

```
Object {0: 1, 
        2: 1, 
        6: 1, 
        8: 1, 
        1: 2, 
        3: 1, 
        5: 2, 
        7: 1}
```

The index that contains the lowest value in it needs to be the very first instance in the new object and it should keep the same index and value. I have tried to use `myObject.sort()` but it does not work on objects. I have also tried iterating through it to make it into an array to be sorted but when I call sort on the resulting array it removes the index.

```
for(indx in mainObject){
    myNewObject[indx] = [];
    $.each(myNewObject, function(index) {
        myNewObject[indx].push(mainObject[index]);
    });
}
```

The above code outputs the last array as:

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 1
3: 2
4: undefined
5: 2
6: 1
7: 2
8: 1
```

Calling the sort method on this array produces this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, undefined]
```

Which is excellent but now the index is not present. Can anyone tell me how to do this I have been scratching my head for hours now trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of objects, that way you can keep the index and value together:

```
array = [];
for(indx in mainObject){
  array.push({ index: indx, value: mainObject[indx] });
}
array.sort(function(x, y){ return x.value - y.value; });
```

---

You might want to sort on the value and then on index, as Scott Sauyet suggested. That would make sure that the result is consistent across different browsers, as they return the object properties in different order:

```
array.sort(function(x, y){ return x.value - y.value || x.index - y.index; });
```

Comment: Perfect! You seem to be the only one that understood exactly what I needed.

Comment: So you're not looking to sort the object, just to get another representation of the data that's sortable?  A much easier problem... as demonstrated.

Comment: While this sort is stable, you might want to consider a variation on [the answer from qw3n](#20366814), and sort with `return x.value -y.value || x.index - y.index` which would also put the indices in numeric order for the same value.  (This might or might not matter to you, but it seemed to be what you're looking for.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Good point, that would make the result consistent across different browers.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not something you sort. You are not guaranteed any particular order when accessing properties from an object. That is why your results are converted into arrays which are sortable.  Here is a possible solution

```
var obj={
  0: 1,
  1: 2,
  2: 1,
  3: 2,
  4: undefined,
  5: 2,
  6: 1,
  7: 2,
  8: 1
} 
var arr=[];
for (var i in obj){
  arr.push([i-0,obj[i]]);
}
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  //use whatever sorting algorithm in here.  I'm not sure exactly how you wanted it sorted

  return a[0]-b[0]||a[1]-b[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a bit confused by your console's output.  Objects are **unordered** collections of properties.  When a console displays an object, it must show them in some order, and usually that order is likely

- the order in which the properties were added
- alphabetically by the property name
- numerically by the property name, if most of the names are strings representing smallish integers

In none of these cases does any sorting of the Object properties change the underlying ideal of the object, and your console is still free to display it as desired.

So I simply don't think you can consistently achieve what you're looking for.  Nor do I think it really makes fundamental sense.

If you want your output as Arrays, then we can talk...